# How do I trim, capitalize, and re-add trimmed characters?

Tags: ruby

I have the string `1. california` which I need to read `1. California`. It would seem to me the proper way to do this is strip the `1.`, `String#capitalize`, and re-add the `1.` but I can't figure it out.

Comment: You can use split method

Comment: The problem here is that there is no good way to do that automatically with names. `capitalize` or `titleize` is not always clever enough: Thinking of names like: District of Columbia, Rio de Janeiro...

Answer (score 3):

Instead of strip (which removes leading, trailing characters), [split](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-split) the string two parts and capitalize the word part, then [join](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-join):

```
num, word = '1. california'.split(nil, 2) # split into two parts.
# => ["1.", "california"]
[num, word.capitalize].join(' ')
# => "1. California"

num, word = '2. los angeles'.split(nil, 2) # split into two parts.
# => ["2.", "los angeles"]
[num, word.capitalize].join(' ')
# => "2. Los angeles"
```

or use regular expression ([`String#sub`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-sub)):

```
"1. california".sub(/[a-z]/i, &:upcase)
# => "1. California"
"2. los angeles".sub(/[a-z]/i, &:upcase)
# => "2. Los angeles"
```

**UPDATE**

If you want capitalize all words:

```
"2. los angeles".split.map(&:capitalize).join(' ')
# => "2. Los Angeles"

"2. los angeles".gsub(/\b[a-z]/i, &:upcase) # gsub with modified regex.
# => "2. Los Angeles"
```

Comment: What happens if you have `2. los angeles` ?

Comment: @nodakai, Thank you for pointing that. I updated the answer to handle that. (specified to `limit` argument to `split` call)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `split` method. Split the string into two parts as follows

```
str = '1. california'.split
```

Then use `join` and  `capitalize` method and again join them as follows:

```
[str[0],str[1].capitalize].join(' ')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
s = "1. california"
s.split.map(&:capitalize).join(" ") #=> 1.California

s2 = "2. los angeles"
s2.split.map(&:capitalize).join(" ") #=> 2. Los Angeles
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"1. california".split(" ").first + " " + "1. california".split(" ").last.capitalize`
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a regexp version:

```
a = '1. california'
first_letter = /[[:alpha:]]/
a[first_letter] = a[first_letter].upcase
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take some idea from the following
1.)

```
str = "2. los angeles"

array = []

str.split(nil).each{|i| array << i.capitalize}

array.join(" ")

==> "2. Los Angeles"
```

2.)

```
str = "2. los angeles"

str.split(nil).collect(&:capitalize).join(" ")

==> "2. Los Angeles"
```

Comment: 1.9.2p320 :045 > str = "2. los angeles"
 => "2. los angeles" 
1.9.2p320 :046 > array = []
 => [] 
1.9.2p320 :047 > str.split(nil).each{|i| array << i.capitalize}
 => ["2.", "los", "angeles"] 
1.9.2p320 :048 > array.join(" ")
 => "2. Los Angeles"

Comment: str = "2. los angeles"
 => "2. los angeles" 
1.9.2p320 :059 > str.split(nil).collect(&:capitalize).join(" ")
 => "2. Los Angeles" 
1.9.2p320 :060 >